# Keeping same color when using "gdalogr:polygonize" function to polygonize segmented image

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, polygon, qgis-plugins, polygonize

This is one example of images that I have:
[image: Segmented image in .png format]

Now I want to polygonize it to get shapefile of different polygons. Every time I run this algorithm I get polygons of different colors but I want to keep colors of polygons same as on image parts that is made from.  Is it  possible, does anyone have code for this?